# Occasional Lags on playing audio and graphic stimuli using Psychtoolbox

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I am implementing a behavioral task and only have images and audio stimuli. Everything works fine except some occasional lags. Sometimes, particularly in the middle of the test, the audio stimuli is played in a stretched manner (Assume that my audio stimulus is 'Turtle' with duration of 1 second, but it plays something like: 'Tuuuurrrrrtttttleeee' with duration of 2 or 3 seconds). During this stretched audio play I feel some lags on the graphics, too. This is going to happen for some successive stimuli and after some seconds (after some screen flips and Audio stimulus changes) it becomes normal again. Consequently, I feel that an extra CPU load cause this. Maybe I have to delete and recreate some buffers or handles. I already tried to delete and recreate Audio player handle, but it causes the Matlab to crash! (This is a reproducible Error!). In the following, I provided some detailed information regarding the way I coded my experiment. I would kindly appreciate it if anyone can help me through this.

Program Details:
I use Audio Player, Graphic Player, Mouse and Keyboard Polling and GetSecs classes and functions. I created the corresponding objects and kept using them to the end of the experiment. My program is implemented in an object-oriented manner.

I use Screen('Flip'), Screen('MakeTexture'), and Screen('DrawTexture') functions to display my images. I create a window with these commands:

```
[window, windowRect] =PsychImaging('OpenWindow', Obj.Screen_Prop.Screen_Num,... Obj.Screen_Prop.Background_Color); 

[screenXpixels, screenYpixels] = Screen('WindowSize', window);

[xCenter, yCenter] = RectCenter(windowRect); Screen('BlendFunction', window, 'GL_SRC_ALPHA', 'GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA');
```

I won't close the window and only flip it. Also, sometimes I use different modes of Flip command to display something while keeping the previous ones on the screen or clear screen using a Flip and display something new.

Besides, I use the audio player of the Psychtoolbox to play my audio stimuli. I initialized the audio player through the following command.
`InitializePsychSound(1); nrchannels = 2;`

```
pahandle = PsychPortAudio('Open', [], 1, 1, Fs, nrchannels);
```

Also, I tried the following options for loading the Audio player with no difference on avoiding the issue:

```
pahandle = PsychPortAudio('Open', [], [], 0, Fs, nrchannels);
```

I always reload the Audio buffer with this command to fill it with my different stimuli:

```
PsychPortAudio('FillBuffer', Obj.Parameters.Handle, AudioData);
```

More than 256 times the Audio buffer is reloaded, and more than 300 times I flipped the screen through the test.

I use Matlab 2017a 64bit on Windows 10 Pro 64bit with 12 Gb of RAM and Intel Core i5-3337U 1.8-2.6GHz. I test another Laptop with better performance and same OS, but the issue wasn't solved. I already updated all my Drivers and the PTB to the latest available version.

List of Info and Warnings that PTB produces during and after each session:

```
PTB-INFO: Using specially modified PortAudio engine, based on offical version: PortAudio V19-devel WITH-DIM

Will use ASIO enhanced Portaudio driver DLL. See Psychtoolbox/PsychSound/PortAudioLICENSE.txt
for the exact terms of use for this dll.


Disclaimer: "ASIO is a trademark and software of Steinberg Media Technologies GmbH."
PTB-Warning: Although using the ASIO enabled Psychtoolbox sound driver,
PTB-Warning: could not find any ASIO capable soundcard in your system.
PTB-Warning: If you think you should have an ASIO card, please check your
PTB-Warning: system for properly installed and configured drivers and retry.
PTB-Warning: Read "help InitializePsychSound" for more info about ASIO et al.
PTB-INFO: New audio device -1 with handle 0 opened as PortAudio stream:
PTB-INFO: For 2 channels Playback: Audio subsystem is Windows DirectSound, Audio device name is Primary Sound Driver
PTB-INFO: Real samplerate 44100.000000 Hz. Input latency 0.000000 msecs, Output latency 39.977324 msecs.


Will use ASIO enhanced Portaudio driver DLL. See Psychtoolbox/PsychSound/PortAudioLICENSE.txt
for the exact terms of use for this dll.


Disclaimer: "ASIO is a trademark and software of Steinberg Media Technologies GmbH."
PTB-Warning: Although using the ASIO enabled Psychtoolbox sound driver,
PTB-Warning: could not find any ASIO capable soundcard in your system.
PTB-Warning: If you think you should have an ASIO card, please check your
PTB-Warning: system for properly installed and configured drivers and retry.
PTB-Warning: Read "help InitializePsychSound" for more info about ASIO et al.
PTB-INFO: New audio device -1 with handle 1 opened as PortAudio stream:
PTB-INFO: For 2 channels Playback: Audio subsystem is Windows DirectSound, Audio device name is Primary Sound Driver
PTB-INFO: Real samplerate 44100.000000 Hz. Input latency 0.000000 msecs, Output latency 39.977324 msecs.



PTB-INFO: This is Psychtoolbox-3 for Microsoft Windows, under Matlab 64-Bit (Version 3.0.14 - Build date: Oct  3 2017).
PTB-INFO: Support status on this operating system release: Windows version 10.0 supported and tested to some limited degree.
PTB-INFO: Type 'PsychtoolboxVersion' for more detailed version information.
PTB-INFO: Most parts of the Psychtoolbox distribution are licensed to you under terms of the MIT License, with
PTB-INFO: some restrictions. See file 'License.txt' in the Psychtoolbox root folder for the exact licensing conditions.

PTB-INFO: The detected endline of the vertical blank interval is equal or lower than the startline. This indicates
PTB-INFO: that i couldn't detect the duration of the vertical blank interval and won't be able to correct timestamps
PTB-INFO: for it. This will introduce a very small and constant offset (typically << 1 msec). Read 'help BeampositionQueries'
PTB-INFO: for how to correct this, should you really require that last few microseconds of precision.
PTB-INFO: Btw. this can also mean that your systems beamposition queries are slightly broken. It may help timing precision to
PTB-INFO: enable the beamposition workaround, as explained in 'help ConserveVRAMSettings', section 'kPsychUseBeampositionQueryWorkaround'.


PTB-INFO: OpenGL-Renderer is Intel :: Intel(R) HD Graphics 5300 :: 4.3.0 - Build 10.18.15.4256
PTB-INFO: VBL startline = 1080 , VBL Endline = 1080
PTB-INFO: Measured monitor refresh interval from beamposition = 16.681891 ms [59.945244 Hz].
PTB-INFO: Will use beamposition query for accurate Flip time stamping.
PTB-INFO: Measured monitor refresh interval from VBLsync = 16.684565 ms [59.935637 Hz]. (50 valid samples taken, stddev=0.069477 ms.)
PTB-INFO: Reported monitor refresh interval from operating system = 16.949153 ms [59.000000 Hz].
PTB-INFO: Small deviations between reported values are normal and no reason to worry.
PTB-INFO: ==============================================================================================================================
PTB-INFO: WINDOWS DWM DESKTOP COMPOSITOR IS ACTIVE. On this Windows-10 or later system, Psychtoolbox can no longer reliably detect if
PTB-INFO: this will cause trouble for timing and integrity of visual stimuli or not. You might be just fine, or you could be in trouble.
PTB-INFO: Use external measurement equipment and independent procedures to verify reliability of timing if you care about proper timing.
PTB-INFO: ==============================================================================================================================


PTB-INFO: This is Psychtoolbox-3 for Microsoft Windows, under Matlab 64-Bit (Version 3.0.14 - Build date: Oct  3 2017).
PTB-INFO: Support status on this operating system release: Windows version 10.0 supported and tested to some limited degree.
PTB-INFO: Type 'PsychtoolboxVersion' for more detailed version information.
PTB-INFO: Most parts of the Psychtoolbox distribution are licensed to you under terms of the MIT License, with
PTB-INFO: some restrictions. See file 'License.txt' in the Psychtoolbox root folder for the exact licensing conditions.

PTB-INFO: The detected endline of the vertical blank interval is equal or lower than the startline. This indicates
PTB-INFO: that i couldn't detect the duration of the vertical blank interval and won't be able to correct timestamps
PTB-INFO: for it. This will introduce a very small and constant offset (typically << 1 msec). Read 'help BeampositionQueries'
PTB-INFO: for how to correct this, should you really require that last few microseconds of precision.
PTB-INFO: Btw. this can also mean that your systems beamposition queries are slightly broken. It may help timing precision to
PTB-INFO: enable the beamposition workaround, as explained in 'help ConserveVRAMSettings', section 'kPsychUseBeampositionQueryWorkaround'.


PTB-INFO: OpenGL-Renderer is Intel :: Intel(R) HD Graphics 5300 :: 4.3.0 - Build 10.18.15.4256
PTB-INFO: VBL startline = 1080 , VBL Endline = 1080
PTB-INFO: Measured monitor refresh interval from beamposition = 16.682040 ms [59.944706 Hz].
PTB-INFO: Will use beamposition query for accurate Flip time stamping.
PTB-INFO: Measured monitor refresh interval from VBLsync = 16.683846 ms [59.938218 Hz]. (50 valid samples taken, stddev=0.083440 ms.)
PTB-INFO: Reported monitor refresh interval from operating system = 16.949153 ms [59.000000 Hz].
PTB-INFO: Small deviations between reported values are normal and no reason to worry.
PTB-INFO: ==============================================================================================================================
PTB-INFO: WINDOWS DWM DESKTOP COMPOSITOR IS ACTIVE. On this Windows-10 or later system, Psychtoolbox can no longer reliably detect if
PTB-INFO: this will cause trouble for timing and integrity of visual stimuli or not. You might be just fine, or you could be in trouble.
PTB-INFO: Use external measurement equipment and independent procedures to verify reliability of timing if you care about proper timing.
PTB-INFO: ==============================================================================================================================


INFO: PTB's Screen('Flip', 10) command seems to have missed the requested stimulus presentation deadline
INFO: a total of 304 times out of a total of 1566 flips during this session.

INFO: This number is fairly accurate (and indicative of real timing problems in your own code or your system)
INFO: if you provided requested stimulus onset times with the 'when' argument of Screen('Flip', window [, when]);
INFO: If you called Screen('Flip', window); without the 'when' argument, this count is more of a ''mild'' indicator
INFO: of timing behaviour than a hard reliable measurement. Large numbers may indicate problems and should at least
INFO: deserve your closer attention. Cfe. 'help SyncTrouble', the FAQ section at www.psychtoolbox.org and the
INFO: examples in the PDF presentation in PsychDocumentation/Psychtoolbox3-Slides.pdf for more info and timing tips.
```

Comment: The code snippets you posted look correct. You only need to create the handle to the audio device once, at the start of the experiment, as you have done. Do you have any other applications running at the same time that could be using CPU?

Comment: I boot up the system and close all of the background applications. So I think no background app is going to interfere.

Comment: Do you set the Priority to 'high' (see for example http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/Priority ) ? Have you tried your experiment on an OS other than Windows 10? A basic experiment shouldn't require anything near the CPU / memory of the system you listed for smooth performance.

Comment: I used Priority set and it makes it better as it happens less frequent but still have the issue and hasn't disappeared completely. I edited my question and append the list of warnings and info messages PTB printed at the end of each session.